# If $xf(x)$ has a limit as $x\to\infty$, does it follow that $f(x)\to 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty } xf(x)=\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Does it imply that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty } f(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{xf(x)}{x}=\frac{\lambda}{\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x}=0,\qquad (\ if\quad\lambda\quad is\  finite)
$$

Answer (score 2):

By contraposition :

Suppose that $ f(x) \not\to 0$, then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to +\infty$ and that verify $\forall n \in \Bbb N, |f(x_n)| > \epsilon$.

Then the sequence $(x_n f(x_n) )$ doesn't converge to $\alpha$. Indeed, it's not bounded : $| x_n f(x_n) | > |x_n| \epsilon \to +\infty$

So $xf(x)$ cannot converge to $\lambda$